# Dimension table, bridge table and fact table join

Tags: oracle, data-warehouse

I have four tables in total:
dimension tables- books and authors
bridge table- book/author
transactions fact

Since there are multiple authors for books and multiple books for an author, to resolve the many-to-many relationship a bridge table is used

Tables Structures are as follows:

Dim_Books:

```
book_id (PK) 
ISBN 
Title
```

Dim Author:

```
Author_id (PK)
FName
LName
```

Book_auth_bridge:

```
book_auth_id (PK)
book_id
auth_id
```

Fact_Sales:

```
Sale_amount
quantity
Book_id
book_auth_id
```

I am trying to retrieve the total sales of authors from the fact table, since I am joining with the bridge table, I always get multiple rows from the inner join and the amounts are duplicated.

How do I write a SQL to get the total sales for an author?

Comment: (1) Please show us your current query (2) Why do you have `book_auth_id` in `fact_sales`?

Comment: Please post your query. If you have a given book that sells for $99, which has three authors, I guess you want each author to be allocated $33?

Comment: (1) Current query:
select sum(f.sale_amount),a.author_id
  from fact_sales f
    ,book_auth_bridge br
    ,dim_author a
where a.author_id = br.author_id
and br.book_auth_id = f.book_auth_id
group by a.author_id

(2) The fact table structure for the existing reports needs to be the same.
Adding the bridge table column will not affect the existing reports

Comment: Nick the answer is Yes, I need allocation for each author

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most flexible solution is to include an "allocation factor" column in your bridge table and multiple that with your measure(s) to get the required proportions.

For example, if you wanted to allocate equally between 3 people then you'd have a factor of 0.333 in all 3 bridge table records. However, if you wanted to allocate 50% to a lead author and split the remainder equally with the other authors you would have factors of 0.5, 0.25 and 0.25